# How to make window occupy all the left screenspace using Gnome window manager?

Tags: gnome, window-manager

Often, when working on my Linux laptop I want to get as much from my screen-estate as possible. This means working on windows as large as possible, but not overlapping each other too much.

The typical use case for me is to have a single window maximized in height `(1)`, then opening another window `(2)`. I then want the second window to take all the remaining space, in width and height.

Another use case is to have a third window `(3)` that I don't really want to see - it's there, together with my height-maximized window `(1)` when I open `(2)` and `(2)` partly can overlap my `(3)`. I then want to make `(2)` again as much as possible but without overlapping `(1)` (see pic below).

[image: windows]

Has anyone happened to find a simple solution for this, except for manually resizing windows?

Answer (score 2):

you should switch to a ["tiling windowmanager"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). it seems to fit your workflow better than the so called "floating" model of handling windows.

you can find a list of such window managers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#List_of_tiling_window_managers_for_X).